# Do I need to Have 16 character sprites if I have 4 classes and 4 races?

Tags: sprite, gml

So I've started development on a rouge-like platformer. It would be difficult to explain exactly what it's like, but that doesn't matter. What does matter is how many sprites I need.
I have 4 classes and 4 races. (As of now, may add more later) Thief, Warrior, Wizard, and Archer. They all have different suits. As for race; Human, Elven, Reptillian, and Dwarven. Since the player can choose their race and class, do I need to make a sprite of every movement option for every combination of these? That would equal up to 16 different sprites. But since I'm adding movement, jumping, attacking, etc... Ugh I'm getting a headache just thinking about it, Help please?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with skeletal animation sprites. 
You need to have a body sprite for each class and each race, but you can have a bone, and split the bone from bodies. Then you animate the bone, and allocate the proper body to it.
means that you design a run animation for bone, then when you need to play animation for any class and race, just apply the bone to specific sprites.
**see [this](http://www.yoyogames.com/blog/43)**.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a lot of drawing anyway, but what you can do is separate the classes and the races from the different movements. For exemple, draw a body without any outfit and any race specific attribut (assuming the dwarf and the elven have the same body size... ). Draw this body in all the positions you want. Then draw sprites with the only the heads of every characters, and then the outfits without anything int them.

Then, for each character, in the draw event, draw the standard body, then the character specific head, then the outfit.

The trick is to draw your body animations in such a way that the outfit and the head stay approximately the same during the movements, and the body does all the moving.

But in the end, all depends on the style you want. I would recommend my solution if you do some pixel art. Otherwise, if your characters are very detailed, you may want to use the skeletal animations as Ali Bahrami suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend creating a basic sprite for each race and then copying it and just adding the appropriate clothing / armour for each class.